# Minimum user permissions required to pinvoke from a web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, pinvoke

I've got an ASP.NET MVC app that p/invokes FindFirstFile and FindNextFile. When I create an app pool for the web site to run under, I'll specify a specific user account that has the minimum required permissions to make these calls.

What permissions should the user I specify have?

Comment: You do know about System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles, right?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is FindFirstFile and FindNextFile, then the minimum security the user needs on the folder is "List Folder Contents".